# Hide and replace BottomNavigationBar once pressed

Tags: flutter

I have a `BottomNavigationBar` which if the user pressed on an icon, then it'll show the `CarouselSlider` and hide the `BottomNavigationBar`

This is my code, but I'm not sure if I'm getting the right index of the pressed icon and  if this is the right way to execute it since I get this error

> The argument type 'void Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter
> type 'void Function(int)?'

```
int _selectedIndex = 0;

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

    bool carosuel_vis = false;
    bool bottom_vis = true;

bottomNavigationBar: Stack(children: [
        Visibility(
          visible: bottom_vis,
          child: BottomNavigationBar(
            items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                label: 'Carosuel',
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.business),
                label: 'Business',
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.school),
                label: 'School',
              ),
            ],
            onTap : () {
              _onItemTapped, 
                  if(_selectedIndex == 0) {carosuel_vis = !carosuel_vis}; // a lot of errors in here
            }
          ),
        ),
        BottomAppBar(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Visibility(
              visible: carosuel_vis,
              child: CarouselSlider.builder(
                itemCount: imageList.length,
                options: CarouselOptions(
                  autoPlay: true,
                  aspectRatio: 2.0,
                  enlargeCenterPage: true,
                ),
                itemBuilder: (context, index, realIdx) {
                  return Container(
                      child: Center(
                    child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          ff(imageList[index], widget.image.path).then((value) {
                            setState(() {
                              finalsd = value; //update the image
                            });
                          });
                        },
                        child: Image.network(imageList[index],
                            fit: BoxFit.cover, width: 1000)),
                  ));
                },
              )),
        ),
      ])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
onTap: _onItemTapped,


void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
      if(_selectedIndex == 0) {carosuel_vis = !carosuel_vis};
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`BottomNavigationBar`'s `onTap` comes with `index`.

```dart
 onTap : (index) {
    _onItemTapped(index);
       if(_selectedIndex == 0) {carosuel_vis = !carosuel_vis}; 
    }
```